# classname.each function is not working for dynamically added functions

Tags: jquery

Below Example is used to add numbers in the text boxes added dynamically.
    First Input tells that the number of text box should be displayed. If its 5  then 5 text box will be displayed.

HTML

```
<div id="maindiv">
Enter Count <input name="test" id="cd"/>
<input type="button" value="GetValue" id="btn"/>
<input name="test1"  class ="test" id="cd"/>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', "#btn", function(){  
    $('#maindiv').empty;
    var count=$('#cd').val();
    var i=0;
    while(i<count) {
        $('#maindiv').append("<div><input name=DynamicTextBox  type=text          class=test/></div>");              
    } 
    $('#maindiv').append("<input type=button value=add  class=btn1 />");                
});
```

it gives output when I use input name -Shows correct answer. I used latest version of jquery. thats why I use document.on

```
$(document).on('click', ".btn1", function(){  
    var sum=0;
    var d;
    $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
        d=$(this).val();
        sum=sum+parseInt(d);                
    });
    alert(sum);
});
```

But When I use class name it shows wrong answer .

```
 $(document).on('click', ".btn1", function(){  
    var sum=0;
    var d;
    $(".test").each(function () {
        d=$(this).val();
        sum=sum+parseInt(d);
    });
    alert(sum);
 });
```

Why classname.each function is not working for dynamically added         elemenets. but if I add any text box(Not Dynamically), classname.each function is    working in that case. Is there any  method for dynamically added class?

Comment: Two elements with same ID `cd`? | Function name should be `empty()`

Comment: Same ID cd does make any effect  on answer

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put a space after `class=test`, so the class is `test/`. The best practice is to quote your attributes.

```js
$(document).on('click', "#btn", function() {
  $('#maindiv').empty;
  var count = $('#cd').val();
  var i = 0;
  while (i < count) {
    $('#maindiv').append('<div><input name="DynamicTextBox"  type="text" class="test" /></div>');
    i++;
  }
  $('#maindiv').append('<input type="button" value="add"  class="btn1" />');
});

$(document).on('click', ".btn1", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var d;
  $(".test").each(function() {
    d = $(this).val();
    sum = sum + parseInt(d);
  });
  alert(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">
  Enter Count
  <input name="test" id="cd" />
  <input type="button" value="GetValue" id="btn" />
  <input name="test1" class="test" id="cd" />
</div>
```

Comment: `.test` includes the input field to the right of the button, did you remember to fill that in?

Comment: You should probably check whether `parseInt` returns `NaN`. Otherwise, it only works if all the fields are filled in.